# Pass data object to another VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, instantiation

I am instantiating a detail view controller that exists in storyboard from a different detail view controller and want to give it a data object. In the starting view controller, I use one object (let's call it starting object) that is linked by a relationship to the second data object needed for the second view controller.  My question is how can I give the second view controller the second data object?  Following code is launching the new VC but without the necessary data:

```
SecondObject *secondobject;
detailVC *secondViewController =
         [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
         secondViewController.startingobject=_startingobject; 

         secondViewController.secondobject = secondobject;
```

Comment: BTW - please stop putting so many tags in all of your question titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, try to pass data to your second VC *before* you push it. This might solve your problem.

Comment: That makes sense. But a problem remains.  It seems that I am not getting access to the second object as when I log it to console it is empty.

Comment: `SecondObject *secondobject;` - it looks like it is empty :D You have to actually instantiate it.

Comment: I fixed it by changing to secondViewController.secondobject = _startingobject.secondobject;  It seems that this view controller only knows about the other object through the relationship.  Your suggestion to pass the objects before launching VC was also needed.  Thx!

Comment: No problems, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

secondViewController.startingobject=_startingobject;

```
     secondViewController.secondobject = secondobject;
```

use this code before pushing new viewcontroller